# Polymorphic to Polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the model Follows which has a polymorphic association many models. I have TimlineEvents which has multiple plymorphic associations with the same models. A user has many Follows. If I want to get all the TimelineEvents for my user, I need to look at the follow_type and follow_id of each Follow and match that to the actor_type and actor_id of the TimeineEvents. I can do this in a long arel expression but it is hard to read. What are my other options?  I have gotten fairly close with:

```
has_many :actor_events, :class_name => 'TimelineEvent', :primary_key => "followable_id", :foreign_key => "actor_id", :conditions =>  Proc.new { "actor_type = '#{self.send(:followable_type)}'" }
```

but it fails because self is User and not Follow when called from the user model. So, I get: undefined method `followable_type' for User. Any help appreciated.

Bonus question: How could I merge all of the three polymorphic associations in TimelineEvents into one?

Comment: Could you possibly post how you have the associations defined between the relevant models (Actor, TimelineEvent etc.)?